# openid authentication simple consumer

Tags: java, openid, openid4java

I am doing a project in which one part is openid authentication. I am using Java.
I downloaded the code from the below site:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-openid/index.html, it said that he used wicket.

I tried to execute with tomcat server. I am able to compile the java files successfully.

But when I tried to run the openidregistration.html and put www.myopenid.com or (http)://pratap533.myopenid.com, it is not at all responding.

I am in big trouble as I have to complete the project to get my degree.

I included the openid4java.jar, joda-time.jar and wicket.jar file and the C:\Downloads\FileServe Manager\openid4java-sample-app\src  all these files in classpath.
So I compiled them and was successful.

I created the wicket folder in webapps and in which I put web-inf. In web-inf I created classes folder and also copied the web.xml in web-inf folder.

In the classes I put all the 4 classes of wicket folder.

When I tried to run the openidregistration.html and put www.myopenid.com or (http)://pratap533.myopenid.com
it was not at all responding..
in web.xml file it is with servlet tags. those tags i did not include them.

Please any body help me..

I think I need to use eclipse, but I am not getting what is the problem.

Comment: and what exactly you mean by not responding at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following steps with the sample code you have mentioned and its working fine for me except i was getting connection failure error which might be due to the proxy network.

here are the steps for you

1. Create a dynamic web-application in eclipse IDE.
2. copy the jars from sample to the jar lib folder in your new project (created in step1).
3. replace the web.xml from the one from sample application.
4. copy the SRC folder from the sample application to the one created by you.
5. If you want to see what is happening inside the application copy the log4j.properties file from sample application to the src folder.

Follow the above 4 steps and you will get a running application what they have in there tutorial.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Sir,i tried what you said.but it was doing by going to the site loading3.widdit.com and saying done and it is not displaying anything

Comment: you means it is not redirecting you back you your home page?

Comment: no sir it is saying in the response message that loading3.widdit.com and it saying done .....then the same web page of mine i am getting..

Comment: it is not at all transforming to the other myopenid.com

Comment: @PratapMurukutla: will see in evening as can't check due to proxy settings.Does not make a difference if you are using netbeans or Eclipse